# php select index where array contains

Tags: php, arrays, search, recursion

is there a function out there to search in a array if it contains a part of a text
just like the jquery(':contains')

and then return the index it is in :)
here is an example to help you visualise it :)

```
$arr = array(
  [0] => 'hello world',
  [1] => 'foo',
  [2] => 'bar',
);
$a = arr_contains('o',$arr); //returns array(1,0);
$b = arr_contains('fo',$arr);//return array(1);
$c = arr_contains('a',$arr);//return array(2);
$d = arr_contains('hello',$arr);//return array(0);
```

if recursively can be done would be a plus :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you will have to write a custom function for matching by substring:

```
function arr_contains($str, $arr) {
    $ret = array();
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            if ($subarr = arr_contains($str, $v)) {
                $ret[] = $subarr;
            }
        } else if (strpos($v, $str) !== false) {
            $ret[] = $k;
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```